# ESLINT_NO_DEV_ERRORS flag not working in Typescript project

Tags: typescript, environment-variables, create-react-app, eslint, yarnpkg

I'm working on a project using the following:

1. Yarn
2. Typescript
3. Create React App
4. ESLint
5. Make (Makefile)
6. Fish shell

When developing, I frequently get ESLint errors they stop my project from compiling. I run my project using `make run`, which just calls `yarn start`. I wanted to create a new make command that lets me run my project while setting all ESLint errors to warnings.

Luckily, Create React App seems to have something for this exact setting, an [env variable](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration) called `ESLINT_NO_DEV_ERRORS`. I created a `.env` file in my root directory, and set `ESLINT_NO_DEV_ERRORS=true` in that file.

However, when I do `make run` aka `yarn start`, it completely ignores that flag and still raises errors. To debug, I printed the env variables in `public/index.html`. My custom env variable was set, but the `ESLINT_NO DEV_ERRORS` was not ([screenshot attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRsIW.png)). The documentation says that it does not need to be prefixed with `REACT_APP_` like other custom environment variables.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Try installing eslint globally and locally.

Comment: What's your versions of `typescript`, `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin` and `eslint-webpack-plugin` are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Could also try using

- `TSC_COMPILE_ON_ERROR=true`
- `DISABLE_ESLINT_PLUGIN=true`

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration/

[image: Webpack advanced configuration environment variables]

However, depending on your dependency version, there might be a bug where some of the environment variables are ignored. You could try downgrading `create-react-app` to <4.0.

Read through this issue for the full context, https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9887.